# Foreign key dilemma

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Hello people I have this foreign key dilemma. Let's say we have Table A and Table B and Table C.

Table A is child of super table B and the records are connected through foreign key on id from A to B (one way). Now table C contains information that could be applied to A and B. I know that having this information on table B will come in handy but I am not sure about table A, technically the information could belong also to table A.

Now my question is, would it be better, to have table A access information in table C through its parent row in table B or make a "shortcut" from table A to table C and reference table C directly?

To simplify those two options:

Option 1: table A references table B + table B references table C

Option 2: table A references table B + table B references table C + table A references table C

Is there any benefit doing option 2 since same information is one table away in option 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FOREIGN KEY` is

- an implicitly generated index (for performance) and
- a constraint (for data integrity);

A FK is only indirectly "how you reference another table".  So, I would prefer you simply talk about columns.  (Any column *could* be used to 'reference' any other table.)

One of many textbook principles is DRY -- Don't Repeat Yourself.  It is a wise principle because *eventually* something will go wrong and the repeated data will become inconsistent.  The extra link from A to C is redundant.

On the other hand, in huge datasets, all sorts of textbook principles are violated to provide the required performance.  (By "huge", I mean billions of rows, perhaps millions, but not thousands.)

Since you seem to be just starting out, I recommend not having the short cut and worrying about performance when you hit a problem.  Yes, it  will take an extra `JOIN`.

For novices, performance problems usually happens pretty soon, but not because of the lack of a shortcut; there are many other lessons to learn first.  Hint:  Learn about "composite indexes"; I think it is the number one performance technique that beginners fail to learn about.  (And focusing on FKs distracts from focusing on `INDEXes`.)